# Order notes being populated by previous orders

Tags: magento-1.7, orders

In our Magento 1.7.0.2 store we have noticed a few orders where backend notes from the same customer's previous orders are being populated for their new orders.

This is only happening for customers who have previously created a customer account when placing an order, and are logging in to make subsequent orders through the same customer account.

The issue is summarised as follows:

1. Customer places an order (order A) and creates a customer account
2. Admin adds notes to the order (held in `customer_note` field)
3. At some point in the future, customer logs back in to place another order (order B)
4. Notes from order A are automatically appearing for order B

The notes I am referring to have originally been added via the comments box at the bottom of the order management page eg:

[image]

The information is being automatically added at some point during the checkout process, unknown to us and the customer (the customer has no way of adding notes/comments on the frontend).

I have checked the MySQL database directly and the comments are being stored in the `sales_flat_order.customer_note` database field.

I have searched through all our custom extension files but did not find any extensions referencing the `customer_note` field, as my initial suspicion was that an extension may have introduced this functionality - but this does not appear to be the case.

How can we troubleshoot this and/or prevent it from happening?